# Unable to obtain status (Disable) of Local user

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I ‘m trying to obtain a list of Local Users with Group Membership and Disabled status. I had some success however could not get the corresponding Disable status of each local user. I’m using WMI in conjunction with ADSI to obtain a Disable Status of local users. The Disable Status property is not available with ADSI. Since, I’m a PS newbie any alternative options or explanation would be greatly appreciated. FYI: These are standalone servers not member servers

```
$adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$env:computername"
$user = $adsi.Children | where {$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}
$user| Foreach-Object {
    $g1 = $_.Groups() | Foreach-Object {$_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $null, $_, $null)}
    $s1 = gwmi -ClassName Win32_UserAccount -Filter “LocalAccount = $true” | % { $_.Disabled}
    $_ | Select-Object  @{n='UserName';e={$_.Name}},
    @{n='Groups';e={$g1 -join ';'}},
    @{n='LastLogin';e={$_.LastLogin}},
    @{n='DisabledSatus';e={$s1 -join ''}}    
       }
```

Output:

```
UserName                        Groups                          LastLogin                       Disabled                        
--------                        ------                          ---------                       -----                         
Administrator                   Administrators                  6/5/2012 5:18:54 PM             OKOKDegradedOKOKOKOKOKOKDeg...
TestUser                Users               10/10/2013 7:11:22 PM       OKOKDegradedOKOKOKOKOKOKDeg..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two changes. I'd add this at the top of your `ForEach-Object` loop:

```
$currentuser = $_
```

And change the `$s` line to this:

```
$s1 = gwmi -ClassName Win32_UserAccount -Filter “LocalAccount = $true” | ? {$_.Name -eq $currentuser.Name} | % { $_.Disabled}
```

Comment: Thanks that’s very helpful. I use your suggestion as guide and added more functionality into the script to get all required information . Appreciate your help.