# ADSI query, I am trying to find the flag for identifying if a local account is disabled

Tags: powershell, adsi

To try get all possible values I attempted to print them all out, I thought this was a simple approach to get the values I am interested in. However I am interested in identifying if an account is disabled or not and it seems to me that this value isn't available for local accounts? That seems crazy so I must be missing something. Any help would be appreciated.

I have checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24152530/unable-to-obtain-status-disable-of-local-user) but that doesnt define the flag, ive tried the obvious (Disabled, Enabled) but as I say no luck and I cant see anything obvious from the results from below.

```
$user_adsi = [ADSI]"WinNT://$ComputerName"
$users = $user_adsi.Children | where { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' } | select *
try
{
    foreach ($user in $users)
    {
        Write-Host $user
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to check `UserFlags` property for the binary bit that represents decimal `2` for disabled users.

```
$disabledUsers = $user_adsi.Children |
    where { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' -and $_.UserFlags[0] -band 2}
```

Since the `UserFlags` (works like `UserAccountControl`) is type `PropertyValueCollection`, you will need to index into its first element `[0]`.

---

You could also use `Where()` method to create two lists of disabled and enabled users:

```
$DisabledUsers,$EnabledUsers = $user_adsi.children.where({$_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user'}).where({$_.UserFlags[0] -band 2},'Split')
```

The `Split` mode will output items that met the condition into the first variable (`$DisabledUsers`) and output the remaining items in the second variable (`$EnabledUsers`).