# How to enumerate available properties of member

Tags: powershell

In the code below there are a number of properties of "member"  I've added "description" property successfully but I can't find out if the account is enabled.   I've tried "status" or "enabled" or "disabled" all to no avail.  I realize it's a member of a group of an ADSI call but, I really need to know if the account is enabled or not.

Thanks in advance!

Full script available at https://github.com/JDogHerman/Powershell_Scripts/blob/master/get-localgroupmembers.ps1

```
Process {
    ForEach($Computer in $ComputerName) {
        Write-host "Working on $Computer"
        If(!(Test-Connection -ComputerName $Computer -Count 1 -Quiet)) {
            Write-Verbose "$Computer is offline. Proceeding with next computer"
            Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$Computer,$LocalGroupName,Offline"
            Continue
        } else {
            Write-Verbose "Working on $computer"
            try {
                $group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/$LocalGroupName"
                $members = @($group.Invoke("Members"))
                Write-Verbose "Successfully queries the members of $computer"
                if(!$members) {
                    Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$Computer,$LocalGroupName,NoMembersFound"
                    Write-Verbose "No members found in the group"
                    continue
                }
            }        
            catch {
                Write-Verbose "Failed to query the members of $computer"
                Add-Content -Path $OutputFile -Value "$Computer,,FailedToQuery"
                Continue
            }
            foreach($member in $members) {
                try {
                    $MemberName = $member.GetType().Invokemember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
                    $MemberType = $member.GetType().Invokemember("Class","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
                    $MemberPath = $member.GetType().Invokemember("ADSPath","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
                    $MemberDomain = $null
```

Comment: Get-LocalUser does not run remotely from what I've found.   Trying to incorporate your first suggestion into my script.  A little mind bending since I'm new to scripting, but I'll do my best.  Thanks!

Comment: Using the example: where { $_.SchemaClassName -eq 'user' -and $_.UserFlags[0] -band 2}

How do I access the users one at a time?

if($member.SchemaClassName) returns an error.

Invoke-Command is a tree I should have barked up a week ago :)  I just need one more property.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63637769/15339544), you can change this part of your code:

```
foreach($member in $members) {
    try {
        $MemberName = $member.GetType().Invokemember("Name","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
        $MemberType = $member.GetType().Invokemember("Class","GetProperty",$null,$member,$null)
        ....
```

For this:

```
$members.ForEach([adsi]).ForEach({
    $enabled = switch ($_.class) {
        User    { ('Enabled', 'Disabled')[[bool]($_.UserFlags.Value -band 2)] }
        Default { 'Not Applicable'}
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        Name    = $_.Name.Value
        Class   = $_.Class
        ADSPath = $_.ADSPath
        Enabled = $enabled
    }
})
```

You can add a `try / catch` logic if you believe it's needed. As also stated in comments, the built-in cmdlet [`Get-LocalUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.localaccounts/get-localuser?view=powershell-5.1) already does this for you.